# jQuery tooltip, hide after.. time

Tags: jquery, html, hide, delay

I'm using the [Flowplayer.org Tooltips](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) and I'd like it to disappear after 4 seconds.

Here's the code for it, can anyone help?

```
$("#search").tooltip({ offset: [45, 170], effect: 'slide' });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit.
Borrowed this from another Stack overflow question. 
It works here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mmRu2/

```
jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){
    return this.each(function(){
        setTimeout(func,time);
    });
};

$('#search').delay(2000, function(){
    $('#search').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);
```

Comment: Haha, that just made the search bar fade out slowly after loading :)

Comment: Edited and put a testing link for you.

Answer (score 5):

After that code put

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".tooltip").fadeOut("slow");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't make it fade out. No effect.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks
Weird because .tooltip is the identifier for the tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried delay?

```
$("#search").tooltip({ offset: [45, 170], delay: 4000, effect: 'slide' });
```

Comment: It seems that that one is for when the mouse is gone, not from the very start...


http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: That's very true, but it will do for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. Jamal got close, but missed the important parts.

Working code to hide a tooltip after 4seconds:

```
<script>
$("s.howTooltip").tooltip({
  //start when the tooltip is shown
  onShow: function () {
    //store a reference to this
    var self = this;
    //start a timeout for 4seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
      //get a reference to the tooltip and hide it.
      self.getTip().hide();
    }, 4000)
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Where does getTip() suddenly come from?

Comment: It's part of jQuery Tools: https://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 0):

try the following callback... hope it will work... but i will fade to opacity 0.8... u can change the rest...

```
onShow: function() {
        this.getTrigger().fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
    }
```