# Display codeigniter form_validation with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, validation

I'm trying to display the login form validation error in a slideDown div that fade after a4 seconds, but it seems no javascript is working inside the if statement. I even try adding a simple javascript alert and it didn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Mike

```
<?php 
               if(validation_errors() && $form == 'login_form'){ 

             ?>
                         <script>
                         alert();
                         //var msg = '<?php// echo validation_errors();?>';
                         //informUser('hellloooo!');

                         </script>

                         <?php 

                         $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('* <span class="popUpInfoMsg" style="color:red">', '</span>'); 
                          echo validation_errors();

                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is I run form validation in the controller as so:

```
if(count($_POST)) {
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->function_name);

     if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
          $vars['errors'] = validation_errors();
     } else {
         //Process form data
     }                          
 }
```

`$vars` gets passed to the view file and in the view file we have:

```
<?php if(isset($errors)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error">There were some errors:'.$errors."</div>";
    } ?>
```

To add a script to this I would just add an id to the error div and write the script somewhere in the view file.  Not going to write that here since there are other questions that explain how to do that, for example: [jQuery tooltip, hide after.. time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020998/jquery-tooltip-hide-after-time)