# Hide tooltip after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an effect, when someone hovers over an element, he sees a tooltip for a few seconds after which the tooltip disappears, even when the mouse is still on the element. This is what I have:

```
<div data-sentence-tooltip="yes" data-tooltip-content: "some content"> some text </div>
$('[data-sentence-tooltip="yes"]').tooltip({title: function(){return $(this).attr('data-tooltip-content')}});
```

I tried the following two, based on other related SO questions:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".tooltip").fadeOut("fast");}, 2000);
```

and

```
jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){
    return this.each(function(){
        setTimeout(func,time);
    });
};

$('[id^="tooltip"]').delay(2000, function(){
    $('[id^="tooltip"]').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);
```

But I think I know why none of these are working. Probably because `.tooltip` or `id=tooltip*` gets added to DOM on-the-fly.

Ref:

1. [jQuery tooltip, hide after.. time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020998/jquery-tooltip-hide-after-time)
2. [jquery tooltip set timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131894/jquery-tooltip-set-timeout)

Comment: is your javascript/jquery code inside any listener or just as soon as the page runs, because if so you probably need to put your code inside .ready() function which looks like this $(document).ready(function(){//code goes here});

Comment: i am using window.onload = initialize_function() where this code goes.

Comment: try using $(document).find('.tooltip').fadeOut();

Comment: Doesn't work. And I think it is because there is no ".tooltip" in the document to find. ".tooltip" gets added to the document only after mouse hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function like so

```
$('[data-sentence-tooltip="yes"]').on('mouseover', function(){
  // if the tooltip is a child of the element that is being hovered on
  // then write this.
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeOut();
  }, 2000);

  // if the tooltip is a sibling of the element being hovered on
  // write this
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.tooltip').fadeOut();
  }, 2000);
});
```

This ensures that your code will only look for the .tooltip after you have hovered on the item which displays it.

Comment: Hey Zoheiry, thanks for your answer. I modified it further to make it work (see my answer). Can you please edit your answer to reflect the changes, so that I can accept your answer. It won't be fair if I take credit for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Taking cue from Zoheiry answer, this is what I finally did:

```
$('[data-sentence-tooltip="yes"]').on('mouseover', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#enclosingParentDiv').find('.tooltip').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Couple of points to note:

1. I applied the "mouseover" to each div, because the user is hovering the mouse on the content in the div
2. I search for .tooltip in the `parent div` because `tooltip` gets added as sibling.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by looking at the element under inspect in chrome. Not sure if this is entirely foolproof and would work with other browsers

```
$('input').on('mouseover', function() {
    if(!$(this).is(":focus"))
        $("#" + $(this).attr("aria-describedby")).delay(800).fadeOut(800);
});
```

if clause is optional which makes this code effective only when focus is not on the textfield. otherwise the tooltip continue to display